# YoloV5 stuck on Adding Autoshape

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, yolo

I am trying to deploy a custom Yolov5 model using my webcam. When I run it for images I get results but when I use it to get live obj detection from my webcam it gets stuck on Adding AutoShape..

```
model = torch.hub.load('yolov5', 'custom', path='best.pt', source='local', force_reload=True)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    results = model(frame)
    cv2.imshow('YOLO', np.squeeze(results.render()))

    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0XFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
    blinker       1.6.2
                  ^
YOLOv5  v7.0-162-gc3e4e94 Python-3.10.0 torch-2.0.1 CPU

Fusing layers... 
Model summary: 212 layers, 20953959 parameters, 0 gradients, 48.2 GFLOPs
Adding AutoShape...
```

Ive tried using auto shape as false or adding a frame size but then I get another error because the image has 3 values while it needs to unpack 4 from my understanding.

Comment: I have also tried   results = model(frame, size=640) and frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 640)) thought it would help but still gets stuck on AutoShape...

Comment: Hi, if you have more info, add it to the question, not comments, please.